# Ubuntu 15.04 with Windows 10 - Windows' system choose screen?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, windows-10

Is there any option to install Ubuntu 15.04 with Windows 10, but without GRUB - with Windows' system choose screen?

Comment: Try using the freeBCD editor. However in my experience that one tends to not work.